# what is the best way to insert only datepart of system date into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm currently using

```
Convert(varchar, Getdate(), 101)
```

to insert only date part of system date into one of my sql server database tables.
my question is: is it the right way to do that or is there any other better method to do it?

Comment: I found the solution. I was inserting datatype varchar to varbinary

Comment: But **why** are you converting the output of `GETDATE()` to a `VARCHAR` when the column `SMSDate` already is a `DATETIME` ???? Doesn't make **any sense at all** .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks. I was getting this error for inserting varchar to verbinary. and I solved my problem by recreating my table and changing [SMS] [varbinary](160) NOT NULL, to [SMS] [varchar](160) NOT NULL,. but you pointed out another thing that i didn't ask for. i.e why are you converting the output of getdate() to a varchar. yes  i didn't notice it. what would you suggest me for that. how should i insert the system date there instead of what you pointed to be as mistake?

Comment: Just insert `GETDATE()` - that's a `DATETIME` already - absolutely no need and no benefit in converting that to a `varchar` (and SQL Server will convert it back to a `DATETIME` when inserting....)

Comment: @marc_s thanks againg. I wish you wrote it in posting an answer instead of commenting it so that I would feel happy to upvote you.

Comment: @marc_s: They may be using the conversion to get rid of the time part. (And just to make it clear, I think the issue they are complaining about isn't about `SMSDate` but about `SMS`.)

Comment: @AndriyM yes that's true, I don't want to save the time part of system date. in that case would it be fine??

Comment: @AndriyM my columns SMS problem is solved. Actually I din't write datatype verbinary for column SMS intentionally. I asked this question because I was thinkging that the datatype of sms is varchar. but when I saw it to verbinary I solved my problem by altering SMS datatype to varchar. but meanwhile marc_s pointed out another mistake. he thinks that Convert(varchar, Getdate(), 101) is not right while datatype of SMSDate is datetime. so is he right? I am doing it to avoid time part of system date. how would you recommend me to do that instead of Convert(varchar, Getdate(), 101)

Comment: I would follow the suggestions in @marc_s's answer, which I can see you've already accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you're converting the `GETDATE()` output (which is `DATETIME` already) to a `VARCHAR` and then SQL Server would convert it back to `DATETIME` upon inserting it again.

Just use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(SomeDateTimeColumn) 
VALUES(GETDATE())
```

If you're doing that conversion to get rid of the time portion of the `DATETIME`, you should better:

1. use the `DATE` datatype (available in SQL Server **2008** and newer) to store only the `DATE` (no time)
2. if you're using SQL Server **2005** or earlier, use this conversion instead - should be much more efficient than two conversions!

   ```
   INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(SomeDateTimeColumn) 
   VALUES(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
   ```

**Update:** did some performance testing, and in this particular case, it seems the amount of work that SQL Server needs to do is really the same - regardless of whether you're using the *convert to varchar stripping the time and back to datetime* approach that you already have, or whether you're using my *get the number of days since date 0* approach. Doesn't seem to make a difference in the end.

The **BEST** solution however would still be: if you only need the **date** anyway - use a column of type `DATE` (in SQL Server **2008** and newer) and save yourself any conversions or manipulations of the `GETDATE()` output altogether.